# Access custom order attributes

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have created three custom order attributes sales_person_name, sales_type, referral

I am trying to access them in a different module.

Can anyone tell me how do I access those order attributes in a different module

Do I have to call some model

I tried

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order);
```

and i got below output but cant get an data in it.

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Order Object
(
    [_eventPrefix:protected] => sales_order
    [_eventObject:protected] => order
    [_addresses:protected] => 
    [_items:protected] => 
    [_payments:protected] => 
    [_statusHistory:protected] => 
    [_invoices:protected] => 
    [_tracks:protected] => 
    [_shipments:protected] => 
    [_creditmemos:protected] => 
    [_relatedObjects:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_orderCurrency:protected] => 
    [_baseCurrency:protected] => 
    [_actionFlag:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_canSendNewEmailFlag:protected] => 1
    [_historyEntityName:protected] => order
    [_resourceName:protected] => sales/order
    [_resource:protected] => 
    [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => sales/order_collection
    [_cacheTag:protected] => 
    [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
    [_isObjectNew:protected] => 
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 
    [_origData:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_idFieldName:protected] => 
    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
            [payment_authorization_expiration] => payment_auth_expiration
            [forced_do_shipment_with_invoice] => forced_shipment_with_invoice
            [base_shipping_hidden_tax_amount] => base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt
        )

    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
            [payment_authorization_expiration] => payment_auth_expiration
            [forced_do_shipment_with_invoice] => forced_shipment_with_invoice
            [base_shipping_hidden_tax_amount] => base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt
            [payment_auth_expiration] => payment_authorization_expiration
            [forced_shipment_with_invoice] => forced_do_shipment_with_invoice
            [base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt] => base_shipping_hidden_tax_amount
        )

)
```

I created order attributes as follows

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("order", "sales_person_name", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute("order", "sales_type", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute("order", "referral", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute("quote", "sales_person_name", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute("quote", "sales_type", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute("quote", "referral", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->endSetup();
```

I am trying to access the order attributes in the below file

> C:\xampp\htdocs\practice1\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php

Comment: Try to load order with your order id

Comment: how did you create the attributes?

Comment: I commented above how i created the attribute now Please answer my question.